# How to programmatically change proxy setting in Android

Tags: android, proxy, android-browser

I am trying to make a simple proxy changer application in android. So I want to know that, is it possible to programmatically change proxy setting in Android.

Comment: got answer for similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697533/manual-proxy-in-android-through-reflection/24797025#24797025

Answer (score 1):

You could use [the Android Proxy Library](https://github.com/shouldit/android-proxy).

Comment: [APL](https://github.com/shouldit/android-proxy-library) development version support changing the proxy only for API version > 3.1.