# Open source proxy which can be controlled programmatically Java

Tags: java, proxy

Problem statement: I have an android App for which I am doing test automation and I am looking for a open source proxy which can be controlled programmatically( preferably Java implementation), I should be able to set server and port programmatically on the fly. Nice way to read to read the intercepts made by the proxy ( request and response ).

note: I am a automation developer developing test automation framework.

Tried so far: Little proxy , it increased my lines of code hugely and I
did not find it fully stable. There were many instances where it could
not capture requests and response.

Comment: which part of the question you did not understand? care to comment

Comment: Off topic. Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Comment: some thing like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697533/manual-proxy-in-android-through-reflection/24797025#24797025